# sed delete trailing pattern of digits

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a .txt file where the last column includes a number pattern after the text like 'Baker 2-13' or 'Charlie 03-144.' I would like to remove all the digits at the end of the line, and just be left with Baker and Charlie. I have tried piping the sed command at the end of my awk statement, with no success.

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,2}"-"[0-9]{1,3}$//'
```

I've tried adding the space and carriage returns to my sed command, but still no luck.

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,2}"-"[0-9]{1,3}\s\r$//'
```

I've also tried this, but it only works when I echo a text sample, it doesn't work on each line of my .txt file

```
echo "CHARLIE 02-157" | sed -E 's/[0-9]*([0-9])+\-[0-9]*([0-9])+$//'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there only two columns? Do you want the original file to be replaced or just dump the results to the STDOUT?

Comment: here is the full statement: `awk -F\| '$7 ~ /-OF|-AR/ { print $7, $3, $4, $5 }' qry_log.txt | sort -u | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,3}$//'` so four columns, and it can replace the original or output to a new file. it doesn't matter that much either way.

Comment: From the four columns, you just wish to filter out the names alone. eh?

Comment: Is your input text file perhaps generated on or modified in MS Windows? If so, you may have to convert it so that it uses unix-style line endings.  Please add the output of `od -c inputfile.txt | head` or `cat -vet inputfile.txt | head` to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple sed solution

```
sed 's/[- 0-9]*$//'
```

This will delete trailing dashes, blanks and numbers!

Comment: That will do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,3}$//' file

cat file
Baker
Charlie
```

You don't need to quote hyphen in the pattern.

Comment: Forgot to mention I was using Bash on my Mac. I tried your solution and got the following error: sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Comment: I am also on Mac and this works there. Most likely you're not using it with a file and using a pipe. In that case just use `sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,3}$//' `

Comment: Yeah, I was piping the sed statement at the end of an awk statement. I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: `awk -F\| '$7 ~ /-OF|-AR/ { print $7, $3, $4, $5 }' qry_log.txt | sort -u | sed -E 's/[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,3}$//'`

Comment: I meant output of `awk -F\| '$7 ~ /-OF|-AR/ { print $7, $3, $4, $5 }' qry_log.txt | sort -u | cat -vte` (and provide it in question not in comments)